# Copy sheet INCLUDING comments

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to copy a sheet from one workbook to another workbook exactly as it is, *including* comments.  Thus far, I have not found a simple way to do this. 
 This is the code which works perfectly well for copying and pasting the contents of a sheet to a workbook *without* comments:

```
Sub copyOrRefreshSheet(destWb As Workbook, sourceWs As Worksheet)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = destWb.Worksheets(sourceWs.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        sourceWs.Copy After:=destWb.Worksheets(destWb.Worksheets.Count)
    Else
        ws.Unprotect Password:="abc123"
        ws.Cells.ClearContents
        ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).Value = sourceWs.UsedRange.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

I am sure it will take roughly one line of code to fix this problem, I just do not know how.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Paste Special, Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change:

```
ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).Value = sourceWs.UsedRange.Value2
```

To:

```
sourceWs.UsedRange.Copy
ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)
```

Comment: Your code should work. I prefer `sourceWs.UsedRange.Copy ws.Range(sourceWs.UsedRange.Address)` but same result. Hopefully you get credit for your first answer!

Comment: This works very well, thank you.  For reference, I added `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after the paste command.  This gets rid of the "large amount of data on your clipboard" error message after each paste operation.